# Jquery code works on firefox 54.0.1 (32-bit) and not working firefox 52.0(64-bit)

Tags: jquery, html

hi the following two codes is working fine on chrome & firefox 32-bit.  but it's not working with fixfox  64-bit  version 25.0...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //   window.onload = new function() {
 // $(document).ready(function() {
    $( window ).load(function() { 
 //     $('.ystq_buddy').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(e){ 
        $(document).on('click', 'body' , function() {
            if ($(".ystq_buddy").hasClass("ystq_swipe-right") || $( ".ystq_buddy" ).hasClass( "ystq_swipe-left")) {
               $(document.forms['f1']).submit();
            }
      }); 
});
</script>
```

also this is not working with firfox 64-bit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( window ).load(function() { 
   $('input[id="tinderquest_positive"],[id="tinderquest_negative"]').on("change", function(){

           if($(this).is(':checked')){

                $(document.forms['f1']).submit(); 

         }
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  jquery.js       this is the only msg I'm getting in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I've fixed the issue using setInterval

```
$( window ).load(function() {

        var submitter = false;
            submitter = setInterval(function(){

                if ($(".ystq_buddy").hasClass("ystq_swipe-right") || $( ".ystq_buddy" ).hasClass( "ystq_swipe-left")) {

                    document.forms['f1'].submit();
                    clearInterval(submitter);
                }

            }, 100);

    });
```